# Как нарисовать пятиугольник в Unity 2D UI, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Мне нужно нарисовать отражение данных на лепестковой диаграмме в Unity. С помощью чего это сделать.Line Renderer? [image: Мне нужно нарисовать отражение данных на лепестковой диаграмме]
Line Renderer

Comment: лично я бы не запаривался и импортировал бы картинку с альфа-каналом необходимого размера. И только при необходимости бы уже дооптимизировал бы через фигуры.

Comment: Очень легко. С помощью спрайта точки и линий(отсутствующий спрайт) можно построить любую ломанную на canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать Sprite Shape